# How can I get this images to merge, when both have alpha values

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm trying to add a border with rounded corners to an image, and I've gotten the outside corners working fine, but I'm having some issues with the inside ones.

The current method produces the output on the right, and I expected it to look like the left hand side.

[image]

```
private function addInnerRoundCorners($radius, $borderColour, $borderWidth){


    $radius = max(array(5, $radius));

    $quality = ($radius <= 5 ? 5 : 10);

    $newWidth = $this->getOverlayWidth() * $quality;
    $newHeight = $this->getOverlayHeight() * $quality;

    $tmpImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);


    $transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($tmpImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($tmpImage, 0, 0, $transparency);
    imagecopyresampled($tmpImage, $this->getImage(), 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $this->getOverlayWidth(), $this->getOverlayHeight());
    imagealphablending($tmpImage, false);
    imagesavealpha($tmpImage, true);

    $newBorderWidth = $borderWidth * $quality;
    $newRadius = $radius * $quality;



    // Top Left
    $corner = $this->getInnerCornerShape(0, $newRadius, $borderColour);     
    imagecopymerge($tmpImage, $corner, $newBorderWidth, $newBorderWidth, 0, 0, $newRadius, $newRadius, 100);


    // Top Right
    $corner = $this->getInnerCornerShape(270, $newRadius, $borderColour);
    imagecopy($tmpImage, $corner, $newWidth - $newBorderWidth - $newRadius, $newBorderWidth, 0, 0, $newRadius, $newRadius);


    // Bottom Left
    $corner = $this->getInnerCornerShape(90, $newRadius, $borderColour);
    imagecopyresampled($tmpImage, $corner, $newBorderWidth, $newHeight - $newBorderWidth - $newRadius, 0, 0, $newRadius, $newRadius, $newRadius, $newRadius);


    // Bottom Right
    $corner = $this->getInnerCornerShape(180, $newRadius, $borderColour);
    imagecopyresampled($tmpImage, $corner, $newWidth - $newBorderWidth - $newRadius, $newHeight - $newBorderWidth - $newRadius, 0, 0, $newRadius, $newRadius, $newRadius, $newRadius);


    imagecopyresampled($this->getImage(), $tmpImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->getOverlayWidth(), $this->getOverlayHeight(), $newWidth, $newHeight);   


}

/**
 *
 */

private $innerCornerImage = null;
private function getInnerCornerShape($angle = 0, $width, $colour){

    $trans = null;

    if($this->innerCornerImage == null){
        $width2 = 250;
        $height = 250;

        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width2, $height);

        $trans = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 68, 68, 68, 127);

        imagealphablending($image, false);
        imagesavealpha($image, true);

        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $trans);

        imagearc($image, $width2, $height, $width2 * 2 + 1, $height * 2 + 1, 0, 0, $colour);
        imagefilltoborder($image, 1, 1, $colour, $colour);

        // Image will be a square, so use width for height too.
        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $width);

        imagealphablending($newImage, false);
        imagesavealpha($newImage, true);

        imagefill($newImage, 0, 0, $trans);

        imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $width, $width2, $height);

        $this->innerCornerImage = $newImage;

    } else {
        $trans = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->innerCornerImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    }

    $image = imagerotate($this->innerCornerImage, $angle, $trans);

    return $image;
}
```

It creates a inner corner shape, then just rotates it around. It has a fully transparent background, but as you can see it doesn't merge correctly.

Anyone got any ideas how I can make them merge correctly?

Again, below is the expected result (left). versus the current result (right).

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your post to include an image of your expected result? I'm having a hard time visualising what you mean and without the rest of your class the code won't run.

Comment: @timclutton I've updated my post, I got the script working more accurately, just having an alpha transparency issue now.